# Firebase Realtime Database Recycler View onclick. Passing image from first activity recycler view to another

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass images from a Realtime Database Recycler View to another activity.

**First activity**

```
 package com.khumomashapa.notes.activities;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.R;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.adapter.RecyclerAdapter;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.Messages;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.interfaces.RecyclerTouchListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Widget
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    //Firebase
    private DatabaseReference mref;

    // Variable
    private ArrayList<Messages> messagesList;

    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private Context mContext;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.products_view);


        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext()
        ,recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PreviewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("images", position);
                startActivity(intent);




                Messages messages = messagesList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(StoreActivity.this, "You have selected: "+ messages.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }

                    @Override
                    public void onButtonClicks(View view, int position) {


                    }
                })
        );




        // Firebase

        mref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        // Arraylist

        messagesList = new ArrayList<Messages>();

        // Clear arraylist

        ClearAll();

        // Get data Method

        GetDataFromFirebase();
    }

    private void GetDataFromFirebase(){
        Query query = mref.child("Wallpapers");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ClearAll();


                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Messages messages = new Messages();

                    messages.setImage(snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString());
                    messages.setTitle(snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString());

                    messagesList.add(messages);


                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), messagesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });





    }

    private void ClearAll(){
        if(messagesList != null){
            messagesList.clear();

            if (recyclerAdapter !=null){
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        }

        messagesList = new ArrayList<Messages>();
    }

}
```

[This is the first activity layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JS4m.png)

**The activity I want the images to be displayed in.**

```
    package com.khumomashapa.notes.activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class PreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView preview;
    Button purchaseBtn;
    Button downloadBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

        preview = findViewById(R.id.ImagePreview);
        purchaseBtn = findViewById(R.id.PurchaseBtn);
        downloadBtn = findViewById(R.id.DownloadBtn);

        String preview = getIntent().getStringExtra("images");
    }
}
```

[This is the second activities layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JS4m.png)

As you can see there's no image showing up in the imageview.
This code does work. It does take the user to another activity, but it doesn't show the image that was clicked in the first activity and as you can see I have more than one image I want to show. The image that was clicked must be shown in the next activity.

So in short what I want to happen is:

1. Someone clicks an image e.g. Abduction, Blue Cinema etc.
2. Then the user is taken to another activity and is shown the image they clicked(Abduction or Blue Cinema etc).

Sorry if I sound redundant, but I've been stuck on this for awhile and the tutorials/posts I read before didn't help, because they don't use code that works with Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: Problem is you are passing position from first activity which is "int" and in next activity you are trying to get "String" so you are not getting any data in next activity

Comment: I understand that now. I managed to find a solution 20 minutes ago. Thank you for your response though.